# Spivak, Ch. 22, Problem 1(ix): Find $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{\alpha(n)}{n}$, with $\alpha(n)$ the number of primes which divide $n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-explanation

In Ch. 22 of Spivak's *Calculus* we are asked to find the following limit

> $$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \frac{\alpha(n)}{n}$$
>
> where $\alpha(n)$ is the number of primes which divide $n$
>
> Hint: The fact that each prime is $\geq 2$ gives a very simple
> estimate of how small $\alpha(n)$ must be.

I thought about this for a while, and then looked at the solution manual. I think I may have interpreted the problem incorrectly, and may have been trying to solve a more difficult problem.

The solution manual says

> Clearly $\alpha(n)\leq \log_2(n)$, and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}
>  \frac{\log_2(n)}{n}=0$

I believe this solution means that the problem is asking for the number of (not necessarily distinct) primes in a prime factorization of a number $n$.

Since every prime is $\geq 2$, this means that any product of prime factors $p_1p_2...p_{\alpha(n)}=n$ is such that $\alpha(n)\leq\log_2(n)$. Otherwise we'd have

$$n=2^{\log_2(n)}<2^{\alpha(n)}\leq p_1p_2...p_{\alpha(n)}$$

Ie, $p_1p_2...p_{\alpha(n)}>n$, which is a contradiction.

The way I was thinking about the problem was that $\alpha(n)$ represented the number of distinct primes that divide $n$.

Questions

- Just to confirm, is my interpretation of the solution manual solution correct?
- If so, what would be a solution to the problem as I was (incorrectly) thinking about it?

EDIT: Quite obviously the answer to the second question is that the limit is the same. After all, the number of distinct prime factors is $\leq$ the number of prime factors. Therefore, if $\beta(n)$ represents the number of distinct prime factors then

$$1<\beta(n)\leq\alpha(n)$$

$$0\leq \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{\beta(n)}{n}\leq \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{\alpha(n)}{n}=0$$

Comment: Either way, the limit is zero.

Comment: Okay, it's true. And obviously so, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually prove a nicer result. So, let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ be a natural number greater than $1$. Then:
$$n = \prod_{i=1}^{m} p_i^{k_i}$$
where each $p_i$ is prime. This is just the prime factorization of $n$. Then:
$$\log(n) = \sum_{i=1}^{m} k_i \log(p_i) \geq \log(2) \sum_{i=1}^{m} k_i$$
Dividing by $n$ on both sides and taking limits, you obtain that:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\gamma(n)}{n} = 0$$
where $\gamma(n)$ is the total number of primes (including copies of a given prime) that appear in the prime factorization of $n$.

Comment: Since $\gamma(n)=\sum_{i=1}^{m} k_i$, I have a hard time seeing how it's actually a function of $n$. Maybe you could clarify? Otherwise, thanks for a nice solution!

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late response. So, the key is that $m$ depends on $n$ itself. Indeed, $m$ is the total number of distinct primes that appear in the prime factorization of $n$ and that will be a function of $n$.